# Store html / website in vb

Tags: vb.net

in my application theres a website that im using, Is it possible for my website files to be stored locally on a user computer when the application is installed? So when a user install this application the web pages will be viewed locally from the html file that was installed with this application.

Files to be stored and viewed in the application webrowser1

```
index.html
css/style.css
js/popup.js
```

How can these files be stored and viewed in the webbrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply store all of the files in a local folder structure, and then make user browser navigate to it using file:// as a protocol in the URL:

```
file:///c:/path/to/index.html
```

Comment: What if i don't no the installation path? How can i choose my own installation path? How can i add the files to the directory of the installation

Comment: It would depend on the way the user installs your application. If you provide a custom installer, you can ask the user where to install the files, keep the track of the path and then create a shortcut for them. If the installation path is not known, the  best you can do is to ask the user: after installing/copying all files locally, please open up the installation folder and double click the index.htm file. That would achieve the same result essentially.